# I need help associating valus to strings in order to calculate an average

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need help associating values to certain strings in order to calculate an average after an user inputs them.
So I tried using string::find since the values are sequential; 
And I ended up with this code:

```
string str1, str2, str3, str4, str5;
string::size_type position;
float media;
str1 = "NSMBE";
cout << str1.find("N") +1  << endl;
cout << str1.find("M") + 1 << endl;
cout << str1.find("M") + 1 << endl;
cout << str1.find("B") + 1 << endl;
cout << str1.find("E") + 1 << endl;
```

But now how I go from here to get the user input and making the strings equal to each value? 
Example: User inputs an N for grade1 and a M for grade2; so N=1 and M=2 , so the average I should get is (1+2)/2. ..

I'm sure it's really trivial and easy to do, but I searched everywhere in order to find a answer and couldn't.

Comment: An awesome place to start would be [cplusplus tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to associate a string (or char) with a value, you should use an associative container such as `std::map`. I am not sure if I understood your question properly but here is something that might get you started.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string str1, str2, str3, str4, str5;
    str1 = "NSMBE";
    map<char, int> values;

    cout << "Enter a letter: ";
    for (char key; cin >> key; cout << "Enter a letter: ")
    {
        int val;
        cout << "enter a value: ";
        cin >> val;
        values[key] = val;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (char c : str1)
    {
        cout << "key = " << c << endl;
        sum += values[c];
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << sum << endl;
    cout << "Value of the string: " << double(sum)/double(str1.size()) << endl;
}
```